# as.Date convert Date in a data frame

Tags: r, date, as.date

I'd like to convert a whole column with as.Date to a date format.

```
str(fluesse)
'data.frame':   1049 obs. of  28 variables:
$ Datum                      : Date, format: NA NA NA ...
```

the dates are formatted like this:

`07.08.14`

This is what I tried

```
as.Date(as.character("07.08.14"), format="%d.%m.%y")
[1] "2014-08-07"
as.Date(as.character(fluesse$Datum), format = "%d.%m.%y")
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I always get NA for the entries in `fluesse$Datum`

and when I try to check what class it has i gives me

```
class("fluesse$Datum")
[1] "character"
```

What am I missing when I try to use `as.character` on the data.frame?

Comment: Can you show an example that reproduce NA (instead of the object name)?

Comment: from your example seems like your `Datum` column is filled with words `NA` not with dates in string format. maybe it's an issue with reading data to the `fluesse` data.frame, not with converting?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your  `fluesse$Datum` in the `str(.)` *is* already of class `"Date"` with all the NAs.
Then below, you show another `fluesse$Datum` which is of class "character", so
`as.character(.)` will not have an effect.

Maybe you just confused yourself by calling both versions `fluesse` instead of say `d.fl.1` and `d.fl.2`  (one convention likes to denote datasets by an initial `d.`)  ?

Answer (score 1):

For all date conversions... Trying the "lubridate" package always helps. Functions like dmy_hms, mdy_hms help in parsing almost any date format. Just install the package and play around with it. I think you will figure out yourself.You can try this:

```css
> library(lubridate)
> x <- "07.08.14"
> x <- dmy(x)
> as.Date(x, format="%d.%m.%y")
[1] "2014-08-07"
```

in place of "x" you can put your date vector and try.

Another possibility is that, the data has not been read in from the source, hence class() on date vector gives character "NA".